# jquery animate scroll to position on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, position

Many related questions but unfortunately not what i'm looking for.

I'm trying to make this function. When the user uses the scroll function, it scroll 550px down, and the next time again 550px, etc. I wrote the following code but it seems that the function runs into a loop. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

```
var start=0;
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    var body = $("html, body");
   start+=550;
        body.animate({scrollTop: start}, '2000', 'swing', function() { 
            return;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to animate to a scroll position every time the `scroll` event fires (which is a lot of times). So by the time you want to scroll to 550, jQuery is still busy trying to animate to 500 (2 seconds is *a lot* of time). To give you an idea, think about 10+ animations running concurrently on the same element for the course of 2 seconds, all with different parameters.

There are a couple of ways you can fix this. The best way in these sort of cases is to use a **debouncer** (also called a **throttler** sometimes).

The easy fix is probably to tell jQuery to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animation it's currently running immediately, and run the new one.

```
body.stop().animate({scrollTop: start}, '2000', 'swing', function() { 
    return;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. The stop() bit didn't help. I'll look into the debouncer/throttler concept, though.

Comment: OK, I figured out why `stop` doesn't work, it's because animating the scroll positions fires, in turn, more scroll events. So, one thing feeds the other, means you pretty much scroll indefinitely. Debouncing might be the best solution after all.